# how to fix this reference error where my function xCoor is undefined

Tags: javascript, class, getter-setter

1. the goal of the code is to allow only positive values for the x and y coordinates of a generic shape.
2. x and y both have to be defined as private members that can only be set after the value was checked, if the value sent to the setter was negative the coordinate will be set to 0
3. lastly, the constructor has to call the setter functions

```
class Shape {
    //takes essential points (EP)
    constructor (x, y){
        xCoor(x);
        yCoor(y);
    }
    set xCoor(x){
        if (x < 0){
            this.x = 0;
        } else {
        this.x = x;
        }
    }
    get xCoor(){
        return this.x;
    }
    set yCoor(y){
        if (y < 0){
            this.y = 0;
        } else {
        this.y = y;
        }
    }
    get yCoor(){
        return this.y;
    }
    showPoint(){
        console.log('(x, y) ' + this.x + ',' + this.y);
    }
}
//so what are the properties of a shape?
//if circle centre would be EP 
//if rectangle the top left corner would be EP

let circle = new Shape(5,5);

console.log(circle);
circle.showPoint();


//the error message

/*
   xCoor(x);
        ^

ReferenceError: xCoor is not defined
    at new Shape (/Users/anthonybarros/Desktop/Tutorial 8/tutorial6.js:4:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/anthonybarros/Desktop/Tutorial 8/tutorial6.js:35:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

try as simple as possible

```js
class Shape {

    constructor (x, y){
        // xCoor(x);
        // yCoor(y);
        this.x = x < 0 ? 0 : x;
        this.y = y < 0 ? 0 : y;
    }

    showPoint(){
        console.log('(x, y) ' + this.x + ',' + this.y);
    }
}

let circle1 = new Shape(5,5);
let circle2 = new Shape(-5,5);
let circle3 = new Shape(-5,0);


console.log(circle1);
console.log(circle2);
console.log(circle3);
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, however, I need the constructor to call the setter functions